# ¿ como permito varios origenes especificos para cors en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cors

Estoy tratando de generar una configuración de seguridad que permita aceptar las peticiones de un archiv. env donde se especifican las urls o ips permitidas

.env

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=127.0.0.1:4200,127.0.0.1:8000
```

Cors.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    //conver to array from .env
    $corsEnable = explode(',', env('CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN'));



    $response
        ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $corsEnable)
        //Métodos que a los que se da acceso
        ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
        //Headers de la petición
        ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization");

    return $response;
}
```

he intando realizarlo de esta forma pero me bota el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: laravel 8.12, para esto cree un milddleware con php artisan make:middleware Cors

Comment: Laravel 8 **ya tiene configurado los cors**, lo puedes ver [acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#cors). Solo debes añadir lo que necesites a las llaves existentes del array en el archivo app/config.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error de la consola es bastante claro. El header xxxAllow-Origin no es de los que permite valores separados por comas para indicar un conjunto. Tampoco es de los que permite enviar el header repetido para tal propósito.

Solamente puedes devolver un valor, por lo que el procedimiento es, dada tu "lista blanca", obtener la IP del request. Si hay una coincidencia le pones esa IP a tu header. A cada origen le dices: "justo, pero justo, estaba reservando este endpoint para ti".

Por otro lado, CORS no es una medida de seguridad para tu backend. Para eso hay mejores herramientas que actúan hoy en día a nivel de DNS. El CORS *es para proteger al visitante*.

Si éste envía un request cross origin y el server no le da el visto bueno, le está diciendo

> no se supone que me estés enviando esa información por Ajax o fetch. No será que te inyectaron un script para generar un token en mi lado y suplantarte? Si realmente te quieres loguear mándame las credenciales con un form y encantado te inicio sesión.

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho me funciono el concepto